# cq5 aem copy a node to all language site pages

Tags: aem

I have a component which creates a node under english language site page.
When this node is created , I need to copy the node to all other language site pages.

I am thinking to create a sling event or jcr observer to listen to node creation. But I am not sure, how to do the copying to the other language pages.

Should I use any specific aem/ cq5 API to achieve the copying the content to a different language page?

Thanks,
Sri

Comment: Isn't this what MSM is for?